# Zend Router Route Regex with Search params

Tags: php, zend-route, zend-paginator

Trying to grab the params after ?. I need them to add to the Zend_Paginator.
ex: http://www.example.com/test/show?name=xxx&age=20&sex=m
Building a paginator for search results.
Is there any solution for that ?

```
$router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
            'test/show\?(.*)',       
            array(
                'controller' => 'test',
                'action'    => 'show',
                'module'    => 'user'
            ),
            array(
                1 => 'q'           
            ),
            'test/show%s'   
        );

        $router_prev->addRoute('view',$router);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following in the controller?

```
$this->_request->getParams();
```

.. or just use the server variable for the query string:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

Comment: It doesn't return the format I like
ex: name=xxx&age=20&sex=m 
to attach to Paginator

Comment: I've updated my answer with the simplest method if you want it as you have stated in your comment.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, works for getting params in the controller.
Do you have idea any idea for Paginator urls have those parameters? 

eg: 
search?name=xxx&age=20&sex=m&page=2